# Serial port communication in windows

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf program for serial port communication. I am using the Eterlogic VSPE, an emulator for serial port communication. First I started the emulator and then debug the program. The program doesn't receive any value. Here I include my code.

```
SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
serial.PortName = "COM1";
serial.BaudRate =2400
serial.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
serial.Parity = Parity.None;
serial.DataBits = 8;
serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serial.ReadTimeout = 2000;
serial.WriteTimeout = 50;

serial.Open();

string received = null;

received = serial.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I advice you to debug receiving data from your device on some third party program, for example Com Port Toolkit. I think your problem in wrong settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me but the 2400 baud rate is very low, are you sure it isn't 9600 or some other higher value? Also are you sure the device is in fact on COM1?

Comment: I put the baud rate as 9600. Now i am getting operation time out exception. Com 1 is fine i think, becuase i can't open com 2.

Comment: It works fine for me, I suspect the issue is more to do with how you're using VSPE. What I did was create a Pair device which created two ports: COM3 and COM4. I then ran two versions of your code, the first was exactly the same as your code but on COM3 and the second was on COM4 and wrote something to the port instead i.e. serial.WriteLine("Hello World!"); As soon as I ran the second program the first one received the string. Baud rate etc doesn't matter so long as both versions are using the same port settings.

Comment: Is it possible with a single COM port for both send/receive in a single program. ( when i send data, simultaneously how i get the response back, using the same emulator VSPE)

Comment: Serial ports aren't really designed like this, data you send isn't normally echoed back to the host. (And why would it be? You already know what the data is on the local machine because you've already sent it). It is possible to set up a serial loopback test but that's usually only done for testing and by physically connecting the TX and RX pins on the serial port (see http://goo.gl/5a7dlO). You can send and receive on the same port but you still need to be talking to something on the other side. That emulator does a few tricks (pairing, multiple processes connecting etc) but not loopback.